# Как использовать redbean в ооп?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

У меня есть код:

```
<?php

namespace PostModel;

require "../vendor/rb.php";

class Model{
    function getPosts(){
        $Posts = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `posts`');
        echo var_dump($Posts);
    }
}

?>
```

Мне выдает ошибку:: Uncaught Error: Class 'PostModel\R' not found in
Что делать?

Comment: А был ли код? Код в вопрос приведите.

Comment: Баги оверфлоу, код был.Перезалил

Comment: Читаейте ошибку: класс 'PostModel\R' не найден. Если класс находится в другом пространстве имен, необходимо указать его.

Comment: В том и дело, что класс R, находящийся в фале rb.php не найден.А как его добавить?

Comment: Попробуйте так `$Posts = \R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `posts`');`

Comment: Появилось еще больше ошибок.Они ссылаются на файл rb.php